# query text parameter documentation for SharePoint search rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

In my custom SPFx solution, I am trying to restrict the SharePoint online search to one list using SharePoint search rest API. I followed the solution given on [technet forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/47125253-2a26-4edf-924e-d762dc77b948/search-in-a-single-document-library-using-the-api-apisearchqueryquerytext?forum=onlineservicessharepoint) But when I went through the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview) for SharePoint search api, I did not find any in-depth documentation for the querytext parameter like what all details can be passed(ex. listid, contenttype etc). can someone please suggest where I can find this information and what is the difference between contenttext and contenttemplate?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to [KQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference#specifying-property-names-for-property-restrictions) and we can pass managed properties as Properties Restrictions.